# Exporting BMC trace flow via Trace32

Tags: performancecounter, trace, trace32, lauterbach

I am working with two HW platforms that include two ARM processors:

- Cortex-A15 and
- Cortex-R5.

I would like to export via Lauterbach Trace32 a mixed trace composed of program flow and BMC values (benchmark counters / performance counters). To clarify my intent, I provide the following synthetic example:

```
Instruction | Cache Misses | ... |
------------+--------------+------
 0x1234     | 1            | 0
 0x1235     | 1            | 0
 0x1236     | 2            | 0
```

I tried to utilize the following commands to properly set the tracer:

```
bmc.PMN0 DCMISS
bmc.export ON
bmc.trace ON
bmc.select PMN0
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to export a trace containing the BMC I set.
I already tried with some of the `trace.export` commands but I never succeeded.

Does anyone know how to produce such a trace? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you SoC is actually able to somehow export the values of the performance counters to the CoreSight ATB? As far as I know some Cortex-M chips can do this via the STM, but I don't thing that this is physically possible with Cortex-A.

Comment: What you always can do is using the SNOOPer to sample the BMC values.

Comment: I am not sure, I am relying on what is written in the Lauterbach [ARM debugger manual](documenthttp://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/debugger_arm.pdf) . The document reports: "The counters of Cortex-A/R cores can be read at run-time.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Cortex-A and Cortex-R the performance counters (aka. "BenchMark Counters (BMC)") can usually not be transmitted via CoreSight trace.
(Btw.: Some Cortex-M can export the BMC via CoreSight ITM. A list of these processors is listed in this [table](https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/oss-platforms/f/dev-platforms-forum/11817/data-watch-dwt-on-rpi3-without-debuigger/34722), DWT column).

However the performance counters can be read during run-time, which allows to sample their values during run-time.

To sample the performance counters during run-time enable the SNOOPer with `SNOOP.OFF` and `SNOOP.AutoArm ON` and select the BMC counters with `SNOOPer.Mode BMC`. View the results with `SNOOPer.List`.

To save the results to hard drive for later analysis you can use `SNOOPer.SAVE *` and re-load it later with `SNOOPer.LOAD *`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you think about bus events (EVNTBUSm)? Can't I trace these events tracing the bus?

Comment: I am not totally sure, but I think you can record those events with ETMv4 (which is used on the Cortex-A15) but not with the ETMv3 (which is used on the Cortex-R5). Maybe you should contact the Lauterbach support about this.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to mark your answer as the one that "solved" my problem.  I am also going to add a link in your answer that could be helpful for someone else in the future.